# Ошибка systemd-sysv-generator

Tags: linux, debian, vmware

Установлена Debian 8 x64 на Vmware 11.0.0

Ни с того ни с сего начала выскакивать ошибка при загрузке и при конфигурации некоторых пакетов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое этих каталогов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Я читал по поводу systemd-sysv-generator. Он используется для какой-то совместимости скриптов. Но я в этом детально не разобрался, и по его мнению `rc*.d` должны быть скриптами. Как я понял... Но они являются каталогами.

Команда `dpkg -S /etc/init.d/rc1.d` дает ответ:

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/init.d/rc1.d
```

И так ко всем каталогам

Comment: откуда взялись все эти каталоги? каким пакетам они принадлежат? (`dpkg -S /путь/к/файлу/или/каталогу`). // текст следует прилагать к вопросу/ответу в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поиск по тексту работает.

Comment: Дополнил вывод команды

Comment: только сейчас разглядел в именах файлов слово *vmware*. разбирайтесь с этой программой — с какой целью она «нагадила» вам внутрь виртуальной машины. // я бы просто поудалял весь этот мусор.

Comment: Это демоны vmware tools. Благодаря им работает вставка и общие папки с Windows. При удалении все это перестает работать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ошибки, собственно, нет: в `/etc/init.d` не должно быть никаких каталогов.

точнее, ошибка присутствует в той программе, которая создала эти файлы и каталоги.

такие скрипты должны располагаться в `/etc/rc*.d`, а не в `/etc/init.d/rc*.d`.

если эти скрипты вам действительно нужны, попробуйте переместить их — из `/etc/init.d/rc0.d` в `/etc/rc0.d` и так далее, а каталоги `/etc/init.d/rc*.d` — удалите.

только обратите внимание, что это могут быть не файлы, а мягкие ссылки на файлы (*symlinks*), и, если пути к файлам в этих ссылках указаны не абсолютные, а относительные, то их надо будет исправить после перемещения.

Comment: Вы правы, помогло. Только почему в этой книге сказанно что эти каталоги размещаются в /etc/init.d/rc*.d https://books.google.kz/books?id=9RoElDoDRCgC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=/etc/init.d/rc1.d&source=bl&ots=ca4nHZajsc&sig=HK5ucA6jNSJut60cHhuFHJsErvw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_-834rZ_MAhXEDywKHcIjDlwQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%2Fetc%2Finit.d%2Frc1.d&f=false

Comment: наверно, потому, что в названии книги фигурирует имя совсем другого дистрибутива.

Comment: Понятно! Значит я собирал из исходников другого дистрибутива VMWare tools. Это все объясняет, просто там было сказано что эти исходники и для debian. Спасибо за помощь!